# Rails Controller not creating new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a definition

```
def create
   @person = Person.new(params.require(:firstname, :lastname, :job).permit(loc))
   @person.save
   redirect_to @person
```

When I try to save a new person I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError in PeopleController#create
wrong number of arguments (5 for 1)
```

Is there an issue with the way I coded it?  I also tried separating out each element with a separate ".require".

Comment: I think the problem is around `params.require(:firstname, :lastname, :job).permit(loc)` can you post params and what fields you want to save for person?

Comment: The error `wrong number of arguments (5 for 1)` would suggest that you are passing 5 arguments to a method, but you aren't anywhere in the code you posted. So, the bug is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: In response to Adrian's comment you might want to post your `Person` model `initialize` as well as any `before_` or `after_` `initialize`

Comment: @Joe's answer below is correct. Parameters your controller is receiving from the view are in the form of a hash called Person. You want to require person and permit all of the other variables. As far as validating that the values passed aren't nil, you can do this in the Model instead of marking :first_name, :last_name, and :job as "required."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you want something like `params.require(:person).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :job, :loc)` then have your `Person` model validate the required attributes.

As for your issue, my guess is if you check your `params` you will see something like `{person: {firstname: "first", lastname: "last", job: 1, loc: "somewhere"}}` coming through and that is why your `Person.new` is raising that error.